# MVC site returning blank page after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 website, which is working fine at local, but on webserver (on sub domain )after deployment, its returning blank page.

I am using godaddy's web hosting, and i have other websites too (in mvc 3 & mvc 4), which are working fine on same web server (other similar sub domain).

I have done lots of google and tried lots of things but, its still returning blank page (no error or content, absolutely noting).

site url: `http://gcms.microlent.com/`

For testing purpose, i have added a webform page and its working fine there:
`http://gcms.microlent.com/webform1.aspx`

In hope of getting some exception, i have added below code, and a error controller and view, but still its not showing any error and any content..

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "HandleTheError");
            routeData.Values.Add("error", exception);

            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();

            IController errorController = new ErrorController();
            errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
                new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        }
```

NOTE: All required dll are uploaded there properly..

Comment: on your url Response status is coming 500 that's mean internal server error and you are using Mr CMS - http://www.mrcms.com may be this cms haven't set error page correctly.

Comment: @govind: I have set the error page correctly in this and its working fine in local. also i have created a application level error controller and page.. but still, its not showing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, resolved the issue.

The issues was with version of System.web.razer and the httphandler was swollowing the exception..

Comment: So... what did you actually do to *fix* it?

Comment: You must mention the type of **fix** you did there